# Please hat the community user

Tags: feature-request, community-user

The [community user](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/-1/community) is showing up in the Ask Different [winter bash leaderboard](http://winterba.sh/leaderboard).

Undoubtedly the community process is working hard, but until now there was no easy way to measure its contribution.

It has earned hats, and we should allow it to wear one.

Please request that Stack Exchange select a hat for the community user to proudly wear, demonstrating its contribution and commitment to a better Ask Different!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I intend to exercise the ability of moderators to issue hats to the community user. The festivities will commence once the proper code is issued to the web engines.

[Community, please show some holiday spirit!](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/159273/community-please-show-some-holiday-spirit)

And we're up and running...

[image: Community Police]

Comment: But with only four hats to wear, community may decide to be boring after trying them on a bit.